# File name change to xxxx.tmp when update file upload Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hello I got an error when i tried to update image file. I have 2 form (create and edit). When I create an user with image upload it success and store with right file name to public path and database (filename.jpg).

But when I tried to update, image file success upload to public path with right file name (filename.jpg) but file name that insert to database becomes `D:/Xampp/tmp/xxxx.tmp`. Can anybody help me? I'm stuck from yesterday.

Create method:

```
public function store(CreateDosenRequest $request)
{
$user = User::create([
    'name'     => $request->input('name'),
    'username' => $request->input('username'),
    'email'    => $request->input('email'),
    'password' => $request->input('password'),
    'admin'    => $request->input('admin'),
]);
if (Input::hasFile('fotodosen')) {
    $data        = Input::file('fotodosen');
    $photo    = Input::file('fotodosen')->getClientOriginalName();
    $fileName = rand(11111, 99999) . '.' . $photo; 
    $destination = public_path() . '/uploads/';
    Request::file('fotodosen')->move($destination, $fileName);
    $data = $fileName;
}
$dosen = Dosen::create([
    'iddosen'           => $request->input('iddosen'),
    'nipy'              => $request->input('nipy'),
    'namadosen'         => $user->name,
    'user_id'           => $user->id,
    'alamatdosen'       => $request->input('alamatdosen'),
    'notelpdosen'       => $request->input('notelpdosen'),
    'tempatlahirdosen'  => $request->input('tempatlahirdosen'),
    'tanggallahirdosen' => $request->input('tanggallahirdosen'),
    'agamadosen'        => $request->input('agamadosen'),
    'fotodosen'         => $data, //you have to add it hear

]);

return redirect('admin/dosen')->with('message', 'Data berhasil ditambahkan!');

}
```

Edit method:

```
public function update($id)

{

if (Input::file('fotodosen')) {
    $data        = Input::file('fotodosen');
    $filename    = Input::file('fotodosen')->getClientOriginalName();

    $destination = public_path() . '/uploads/';
    Request::file('fotodosen')->move($destination, $filename);
    $data = $filename;


}
    $dosenUpdate = Request::only(['nipy', 'namadosen', 'alamatdosen', 'notelpdosen', 'tempatlahirdosen', 'tanggallahirdosen', 'statusdosen', 'fotodosen']);
    $user = User::find($id);
    $user->dosen()->update($dosenUpdate);
    if(Auth::user()->admin==1) {
        return redirect('/admin/dosen')->with('message', 'Data berhasil diubah!');
    }

    return redirect('/dosen')->with('message', 'Data berhasil diubah!');


}
```